# javascript game help pls

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-helper

The game is able to get unlimited money by pressing the button. How do I prevent this?

```js
var workbard = document.getElementById("workbar");
function work() {
  var zaman = setInterval(function () {
    workbard.value +=1;
    if (workbard.value == 10) {
      workbard.value -=11;
      workbard.style.visibility = 'hidden'
      clearInterval(zaman);
      money = money +=5;
      experience = experience +=10;
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML= ":" +money;
      document.getElementById("exp").innerHTML=":" +experience;
    }
```

```html
<progress id="workbar" alue="0" max="10"></progress>
<button type ="button"id="workb2"onclick="work(),document.getElementById('workbar').style.visibility='visible'">Work</button>
```

Comment: The code you've posted has a syntax error.  If this isn't your exact code, please update it.

Comment: what should the limit be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize some variables, add a limit and then use an if statement

```js
var workbard = document.getElementById("workbar");
var money = 0;
var experience=0;
var limit = 30;
function work() {
  var zaman = setInterval(function () {
    workbard.value +=1;
    if (workbard.value == 10) {
      workbard.value -=11;
      workbard.style.visibility = 'hidden'
      clearInterval(zaman);
      money = money +=5;
      if(money > limit)money = limit;
      experience = experience +=10;
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML= ":" +money;
      document.getElementById("exp").innerHTML=":" +experience;
    }})}
```

```html
<progress id="workbar" alue="0" max="10"></progress>
<button type ="button"id="workb2"onclick="work(),document.getElementById('workbar').style.visibility='visible'">Work</button>

<div id='para'></div>
<div id='exp'></div>
```